# Split a string value and then create a new one using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json file with the following structure

```
 [
        {
            "name": "Collection 1",
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": 302,
                    "description":"Book destined for kids",
                },
                {
                    "id": 304,
                    "description":"Book destined for Teen",
                },
                {
                    "id": 305,
                    "description":"Only for teen under the age of 13",
                },
            ]
        },

      {
            "name": "Collection 1",
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": 400,
                    "description":"books for adults to read",
                },
     
            ]
        },

    ]
```

I need to add a new key/value which value should be a substring of **description** Something like [teen,kids,adults]

**Expected output:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Collection 1",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 302,
                "description":"Book destined for kids",
                "age range":"kids"
            },
            {
                "id": 304,
                "description":"Book destined for Teen",
                "age range":"teen"
            },
            {
                "id": 305,
                "description":"Only for teen under the age of 13",
                "age range":"teen"
            },
        ]
    },

  {
        "name": "Collection 2",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 400,
                "description":"books for adults to read",
                "age range":"adults"
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Anyone know a way How to do it in effective way using **pandas** please(I need to keep the same structure)

Comment: Would it be ok to use `nltk`? That is one of the standard procedures for something like this

Comment: Just being pedantic, but anyone under the age of 13 is not a teen. A "tween" perhaps, but not a teen.

Comment: Why don't you use a for loop and regex in order to check whether a value exists in the description of not? Do you have specific reason for using just pandas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nltk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import json

age_keywords = ["kids", "adults", "teen"] #Extend if needed

#json string to json object
json_string = '[{"name": "Collection 1","details": [{"id": 302,"description":"Book destined for kids"},{"id": 304,"description":"Book destined for Teen"},{"id": 305,"description":"Only for teen under the age of 13"}]},{"name": "Collection 1","details": [{"id": 400,"description":"books for adults to read"}]}]'
json = json.loads(json_string)

#iterate details of every book
for collection in json:
    for detail in collection['details']:
        description = detail['description'] # get description
        for keyword in age_keywords: #iterate every keyword
            if keyword in description.lower(): #check if keyword is in description
                detail['age_range'] = keyword #if keyword in description --> add age_range to json
print(json)
#save json to file --> data.json = filename
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

But i didn't really understand where you want to use pandas?

This is my json output:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Collection 1",
      "details":[
         {
            "id":302,
            "description":"Book destined for kids",
            "age_range":"kids"
         },
         {
            "id":304,
            "description":"Book destined for Teen",
            "age_range":"teen"
         },
         {
            "id":305,
            "description":"Only for teen under the age of 13",
            "age_range":"teen"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Collection 1",
      "details":[
         {
            "id":400,
            "description":"books for adults to read",
            "age_range":"adults"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: This works but when i load the file i got this error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`

Comment: Mabye your loaded file is already of type json. Try to this comment line json = json.loads(json_string) Then directly iterate over the loaded string.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I added some code to the answer in the top. I think this should work, but didn't tried it my self --> data.json is your file name.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pandas` and regular expressions, you can parse this data, clean it up, and then apply a regular expression to extract the mention of your keywords:

```py
out = (
    pd.json_normalize(data, 'details', 'name')
    .assign(
        description=lambda df: df['description'].str.lower(), 
        age_range=lambda df: df['description'].str.extract(r'(kid|teen|adult)')
    )
)

print(out)
    id                        description          name age_range
0  302             book destined for kids  Collection 1       kid
1  304             book destined for teen  Collection 1      teen
2  305  only for teen under the age of 13  Collection 1      teen
3  400           books for adults to read  Collection 1     adult
```

Comment: Thanks but in json_normalize raise notimplementederror

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using? `json_normalize` has been available since version 0.25.0.

Comment: I fixed the error thanks but still not the best solution for me :(